# How to make Excel Chart read-only

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-charts

I am working on an Excel add-in and need to show charts to users. However when I open a chart programmatically, users can change its heading/legends/color etc. I want to restrict user from doing so. Is there a way to make charts read-only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel does not support making a chart read-only if the user has editing permission to the worksheet, so you can't do this in an add-in either. You might be able to achieve your scenario by making the worksheet on which the chart appears read-only. You do that by calling the [Excel.worksheetprotection.protect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetprotection?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-worksheetprotection-protect-member(1)) method.